# NOT IN Clause : how to get all the users that doesnt have ALL the elements inside NOT IN parentheses

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem getting the users that doesnt have **ALL** the roles ID inside the parentheses.
The query bellow returns the user if he does not have one of these roles.

SQL Query :

```
select user_id,group_id,role_id from user_group_role where role_id not in (23,98,105,3310,4928,4929,4930) ;
```

Example of the user_group_role :

```
 USER_ID       GROUP_ID      ROLE_ID       
---------- --------------- --------------- 
 3256          2                23
 3256          3                98
 3256          2                4928
 4             2                54
 3256          1                4929
 3256          1                4930
 10256         3                23 
 62            2                105  
 700           2                3310
 899           2                41
 3256          1                105
 3256          1                3310
 3256          1                4930
 62            2                4930
```

In this example, the user 3256 have all the roles_id, the user 62 have only the 4930 and 105 role_id, the user 4 have none of these role_id, in my case i want my query to return the user 4 for example.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: By "not all" to you mean the user has NONE of those roles or the user has some but not ALL of those roles?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a separate list of users, I would recommend:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from user_group_role ugr
                  where ugr.user_id = u.user_id and
                        ugr.role_id in (23, 98, 105, 3310, 4928, 4929, 4930) 
                );
```

I recommend this because this will include users who are not in the `user_group_role` table, so the list seems more complete.  Of course, you may only want users who have at least one row in the table, in which case `users` would not be needed for this query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by each user and take only those having none of these roles.

```
select user_id
from user_group_role 
group by user_id
having sum(case when role_id in (23,98,105,3310,4928,4929,4930) then 1 end) = 0
```

The `having` clause is like `where` but for groups of data and not just a single record.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique constraint on user and role (meaning a user can't be assigned the same role twice, even in multiple groups), then you could do:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user_group_role ugr
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(
    CASE WHEN role_id IN (23,98,105,3310,4928,4929,4930) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < 7
```